Latin equivalent of derogatory Italian "frociaggine"
Pope Francis has recently got into some hot water for using the derogatory Italian word frociaggine "faggotry".
Seeing as the Vatican has Latin as an official language, this raises the question of what the closest Latin equivalent would be.
There is no shortage of terms roughly equivalent to Italian frocio (e.g. pathicus or cinaedus), but it's not so obvious what the most Latinate way to derive an appropriate abstract (and ideally pejorative) noun from this would be.
Answers focussing on Late or Medieval Latin would probably be most appropriate, seeing as we're discussing Popes and the church, but answers aimed at Classical or even Old Latin would also be appreciated.

Do you believe the world would be made better by an answer to this question?

@Cairnarvon I don't think it would make the world worse, and it would amuse me and several others in my queer friendgroup so, in a minute way, I guess so? Ofc ymmv and you're free to ignore or downvote it on that basis

No noun form of either of those words is attested to my knowledge, but there are a few abstract noun-forming suffixes in Latin (-(i)tas, -ia, -itia), any of which would work with cinaedus or pathicus as far as I know. I would go with cinaeditas personally.
